# The events are not POSTING to our API for Full Calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, fullcalendar

Why is the following not POSTING events to our API?
We're trying to make a customizable calendar using Full Calendar, that allows users to add a new event, then the event is posted to our API.  Everything is working, except for the event being posted to our API.   Does anyone have any idea why this is?  Many, many thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>How to add calendar using jQuery and fullCalendar</title>
    <!--FullCalendar Dependencies-->
  <link href='https://www.findvolunteerships.com/fc/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://www.findvolunteerships.com/fc/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullcalendar.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <script src='fc/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='fc/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='fc/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src='http://qtip2.com/static/javascripts/libs/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.2/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.3/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/js/mandrill.js"></script>


<!--jQuery-->
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>



     <!--FullCalendar-->
     <script src='https://www.findvolunteerships.com/fc/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">








    /*
        jQuery document ready
    */

        $(document).ready(function()
    {
        /*
            date store today date.
            d store today date.
            m store current month.
            y store current year.
        */
        var date = new Date();
         var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        /*
            Initialize fullCalendar and store into variable.
            Why in variable?
            Because doing so we can use it inside other function.
            In order to modify its option later.
        */

          var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            /*
                header option will define our calendar header.
                left define what will be at left position in calendar
                center define what will be at center position in calendar
                right define what will be at right position in calendar
            */
            header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            /*
                defaultView option used to define which view to show by default,
                for example we have used agendaWeek.
            */
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            /*
                selectable:true will enable user to select datetime slot
                selectHelper will add helpers for selectable.
            */
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            /*
                when user select timeslot this option code will execute.
                It has three arguments. Start,end and allDay.
                Start means starting time of event.
                End means ending time of event.
                allDay means if events is for entire day or not.
            */
            select: function(start, end, allDay)
            {
                /*
                    after selection user will be promted for enter title for event.
                */
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                /*
                    if title is enterd calendar will add title and event into fullCalendar.
                */
                if (title)
                {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            /*
                editable: true allow user to edit events.
            */
            editable: true,
            /*
                events is the main option for calendar.
                for demo we have added predefined events in json object.
            */
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }
    #calendar
    {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
 </style>



 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function savedata(){
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $("#save").click(function () {
        var eventsFromCalendar =   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        alert(eventsFromCalendar);
        $.ajax(
    {

        url: 'API LINK',
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        data: { eventsJson: JSON.stringify(eventsFromCalendar) },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            debugger;
            alert(xhr);
        }

    });
    });
});
 });
 }
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<!--FullCalendar container div-->
<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click event (and the document.ready event that contains it) are inside the function savedata.  I don't see that getting called anywhere, and even if it does get called, odds are the ready event would have already fire.  You need to remove that function wrapper.  I also don't see an element with an id of "save" in your sample either, but maybe it is getting added through some of you external code.

Also, as a side note, you are including the same libraries multiple times (some of them different versions).  That is...not good.